# How to return an array into an HTML table using PHP

Tags: php

I am pulling data lines from a .txt file and I am attempting to insert it into an HTML table. Right now I am stuck on outputting the array. I am able to turn the line I exploded into an array by re-exploding the line. I var_dumped the new line to ensure it is an array. I need to return a function that outputs the data into an HTML table. I do not know where to go from here. Any help is appreciated. This is as far as I got. For the sample there are about 10 books in the .txt file. Do I include HTML in the same function? or outside and how do I implement? Thank you.

PHP

```
function displayTable($filename)
{


 $table = "\n<table border='1'>";
           $table .= "<tr>";
           $table .= "<th>Title</th>";
           $table .= "<th>Author</th>";
           $table .= "<th>ISBN</th>";
           $table .= "<th>City</th>";
           $table .= "</tr>\n\n";

        $line_ctr = 0;

        $fp = fopen($filename, 'r');   //op

ens the file for reading

    if ($fp)
    {
        while(true)
        {

            $line = fgets($fp);

            if (feof($fp))
            {
                break;


    }

    $line_ctr++;

    //Explode into string
list($title, $author, $isbn, $city) = explode('*', $line);
$new_line = explode('*', $line);

var_dump($new_line);
}

    fclose($fp ); //Close file
}
```

CURRENT OUTPUT SAMPLE

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(14) "Smart Living" [1]=> string(7) "health" [2]=> string(10) "2005-09-12" [3]=> string(13) "1-4145-5896-x" [4]=> string(2) " " } 

 array(5) { [0]=> string(14) "Make Money Sleeping" [1]=> string(7) "health" [2]=> string(10) "2009-01-08" [3]=> string(13) "1-4888-5896-x" [4]=> string(2) " " }
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your commnet. You want to sort the table. I've rewritten this function, hopefully, to help you.

You can split it to 3 step: 1.read file, 2.sort data, 3.output HTML.

```
function displayTable($filename)
{
    // 1. read file to array
    $data = array(); // Save all data read from txt file.
    $fp   = fopen($filename, 'r'); //opens the file for reading
    if ($fp) {
        while (true) {
            $line = fgets($fp);
            if (feof($fp)) {
                break;
            }
            $new_line = explode('*', $line);
            $data[]   = $new_line; // save to data
        }
        fclose($fp); //Close file
    }

    // 2. sort data, example for sort by ISBN
    if ($data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $ISBN[$key] = $value[2]; //sort by ISBN
        }
        array_multisort($ISBN, SORT_ASC, $data);
    }

    // 3. output to HTML
    $table = "\n<table border='1'>";
    $table .= "<tr>";
    $table .= "<th>Title</th>";
    $table .= "<th>Author</th>";
    $table .= "<th>ISBN</th>";
    $table .= "<th>City</th>";
    $table .= "</tr>\n\n";
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $table .= "<tr><td>" . join("</td><td>", $value) . "</td></tr>";
    }
    $table .= "</table>";
    return $table;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $new_line = explode('*', $line);
    $table .= "<tr><td>" . join("</td><td>", $new_line) . "</td></tr>";
}


return $table;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider adding some explanatory text to say how this solves the problem, and what the root cause is. Please also take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: @Williams, thank you for the input, this code does output the table, the only thing is I need it to return with the ability to be sorted. Can you show me how I would sort this table? Thank you.